# Kentico Installation Manager deploy feature

Tags: kentico

I have a question regarding KIM for *Kentico 11 CMS*, about it's **Deploy** feature. Documentation states that:

> Deploy to ... - allows you to deploy web site projects to a specific directory or remote server. The deployment copies the content of the CMS folder, which you can then use as the physical path of an application in IIS. The Deploy to functionality is not available for web application projects.

Is this therefore recommended way to Deploy a kentico instance (database + codebase) to a production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the option to use KIM is there, but I for example use manual file transfer and DB restore. There is no best way on how to do that and in the end it is just another code that needs to be moved along with database.

Summary of best practices can be found on [Kentico Advantage](http://advantage.kentico.com/deploying) site.